# Is there a way to include locally cached items in query of DBSet?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I'm just getting my feet wet with Entity Framework, but I'm a bit baffled by some of the behavior of the DBSet Object.   When I invoke the Find() method, it seems to be aware of my collection of recently-added (but not yet saved) items, but when I try to query the DBSet, it seems to only include items that have been there all along.  Is there an easy way to work around this?   I'm including some code that I've done to try to work around this, but when it starts to iterate through the items from my "Added" change set, I get this error:

> "Unable to create a constant value of type EntityType. Only primitive
>   types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this
>   context."

```
internal DbContext Context  { get; set; }
protected DbSet<T> DBSet    { get; set; }

public virtual IEnumerable<T> Get(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
    bool ignoreCachedChanges = false)
{
    IQueryable<T> oReturn = DBSet;

    // This block is intended to adjust the queryable source to account for changes
    if (!ignoreCachedChanges)
    {
        oReturn = oReturn.Except(Context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where(x => x.State == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted).Select(x => x.Entity));
        oReturn = oReturn.Union(Context.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where(x => x.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added).Select(x => x.Entity));
    }
    if (filter != null)
        oReturn = oReturn.Where(filter);

    if (orderBy != null)
        return orderBy(oReturn).ToList();
    else
        return oReturn.ToList();
}

// NOTE: Get By ID uses Find which considers the queued-but-not-yet-applied changes
public virtual T GetByID(object id)
{
    return DBSet.Find(id);
}
```

(In case context helps, I'm doing this because I want to set up a unit test where I populate my (local) context with items that cater to my particular testing environment...I'd just as soon not have to apply those changes since they're really only applicable for that particular test, but I can if need be...In doing that, I was surprised to see that the repository was not including changed items in its queried results -- unless I was doing the FindByID -- so I'm also hoping I can either resolve that apparent inconsistency, or get a better undersanding of why that's not doable...or not a good idea? :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception says it: You cannot send a list of entity types (of your generic type T) to the server to execute `Except` and `Union` in SQL with these collections of "constant" objects. Basically you must apply `Except` and `Union` in memory with LINQ to Objects, which means: *after* the filtered result from the server has been materialized (so, somewhere after `.ToList()`). You have to apply the filter a second time to the list of objects in the context which are in `Added` state.

Comment: Thanks! This gives me a much better understanding of what's going on.

As an aside, if you happen to read this: is this a wise approach for my repository query methods?   I would tend to think that since this "offline" collection has the queued Insertions/Deletions, it should account for those (as DBSet.Find() seems to do), but is there a reason to NOT do this that I might be overlooking?

Comment: @Steven: `Find` is very special. It queries only for the primary key. This works in memory (1st step) and in SQL (2nd step if nothing has been found in the 1st step). For other queries you must keep in mind that EF had to do a query with LINQ to Entities and then a query with LINQ to Objects to build the union. There are queries which can't even be done in LINQ to Objects (when using `EntityFunctions` for instance). Or same queries can behave differently (case-sensitivity for string search for example). It's not easy or impossible to always do both queries with only one query specification.

Comment: (Continued) Probably the reason why it isn't implemented as you would like it. Those are also the reasons against your general generic implementation to build a union of DB-queried objects and objects in the ChangeTracker: Your `filter` can give different results when applied to LTO or LTE or it even doesn't work with LTO. I have doubt that a clean generic implementation is possible. I would try to avoid that you need to query the `ChangeTracker` at all. If you really need, don't try a generic approach, do it only in your specific scenario and for the specific query where you must.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.   That makes sense and gives me a good deal of info to think about.